# Format String is not string literal

Tags: objective-c

How do i make this a more secure method? As this relies upon an array to distribute the information that can be appended outside of an app update.

```
methods = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"martingale", @"reverse_martingale", nil];
methodString = [NSString stringWithFormat:methods[0]];
```

<- Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)

Comment: There is no reason to create a new string (or use a format) for that... `methodString = methods[0];`

Comment: I cut these out of an existing structure, and it's required to have the methodString as methods is put against an isEqual to update a label as well as a value.

Comment: I always get downvoted, I think this is a pretty solid question, the downvoter could at least give their opinion on the matter.

Comment: The down voter probably expected you to know the answer. What is wrong is to ask "how do I make this more secure". You should ask "what is wrong with this code"

Comment: @gnasher729 as the warning I am receiving says it's potentially insecure, I wanted to know the best way to make it secure. And I assumed that a topic title of "what's wrong with this" would've had me thrown out to the dogs, but clearly that is the case anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply dump the use of `stringWithFormat` given:

1. Those aren't format strings.
2. You aren't formatting anything.

Use this instead:

```
methodString = methods[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's strange. I've never used this, even after two app releases. I really didn't think it was as simple as that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you realise what you are doing? methods [0] is used as  *format* string, as they are used for printf or NSLog. If you change it from @"martingale" to @"martingale %s" then it will likely crash. If you didn't want to use a format string, don't call stringWithFormat.

Comment: so the correct way of doing this would be as simple as `methodString = method[0];` ?